# find the limit of the sequence if it exists $x_n= (-1)^n/n$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the limit $\lim_{ n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ if  $x_n=(-1)^n/n.$

I have proved before a similar sequence $x_n= \frac{(-1)^nn}{(2n+1)}.$

by contradiction, I assumed if $x_n$ is convergent then let $y_n= n/(2n+1) $ and by using a property that states: let $x_n$ and $y_n$ convergent sequences ($x_n/y_n$) converges to x/y provided $y\neq 0$ and got that the sequence is divergent.

Can I do the same with the sequence above?

Thank you for any help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|(-1)^n/n| = 1/n$. This can be made arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$ \dfrac{-1}{n} \leq \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} \leq \dfrac{1}{n} $$

and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{-1}{n} = 0 \hspace{1 cm} \textrm{and} \hspace{1 cm} \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} = 0$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then when $n>N$, we know $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. Since $n>0$, we know
$$
\frac{1}{n}=\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|=\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|=\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right|,
$$
so $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right|<\epsilon$ when $n>N$. By the definition of a convergent sequence, this implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)=0.
$$

Comment: thank you so much :) I don't know whats wrong with me its simple..